# need help for fullcalendar jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add this fullcalendar to my yii app. and because of this is my first time, I've already try to learn the tutorial from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs . but it's quietly hard for me to understand because I'm weak in JQuery, JSON and others. so anyone can help me, step by step, what I need to do to add events from my database?

this is my json-events.php:

```
<?php

$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT TASKID, STARTTIME, ENDTIME
            FROM task');

$result = $query->queryAll();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row['TASKID'],
        'start' => $row['STARTTIME'],
        'end' => $row['ENDTIME'],
        'allDay' => false,
        'editable' => true,
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

is this correct or not? and in where directory should I put this php?

and this is my calendar.js:

> jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>           eventSources: [
>
> ```
>     // your event source
>     {
>         url: '/path/todirectory/protected/views/task/json-events.php',
>         backgroundColor: '#3D8BFF',
>         textColor: '#7AE4FF'
>     }
>
>     ],
>     header: {
>         left: 'prev,next today',
>         center: 'title',
>         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
>     },
>     editable: true,
>     droppable: true, 
>     drop: function(date, allDay) { 
>
>         var originalEventObject = jQuery(this).data('eventObject');
>         var copiedEventObject = jQuery.extend({}, originalEventObject);
>
>         copiedEventObject.start = date;
>         copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
>
>         jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
>
>         jQuery(this).remove();
>
>     }
>
> });
> ```

another things to ask, when I tried to add events with array, it works. but it's not draggable. how to make it draggable?

Please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1st bad reason to make request to `protected`, You need to create action for output json

in TaskController.php

```
public function actionGetTasks()
{
  $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT TASKID, STARTTIME, ENDTIME
            FROM task');
  $result = $query->queryAll();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
      $data[] = array(
          'id' => $row['TASKID'],
          'start' => $row['STARTTIME'],
          'end' => $row['ENDTIME'],
          'allDay' => false,
          'editable' => true,
      );
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Change path in fullcalendar

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({ eventSources: [
    // your event source
    {
        url: '/path/todirectory/index.php?r=task/getTasks',
```

For draggable you requirements read this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/Requirements/

Do you add `Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerCode('jquery.ui');` ?

---

Update:

You need include any js via 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile,

and where you're include js you need also add before : (it may be in /views/layout/main.php)

```
Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerCode('jquery.ui');
Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/plugins/fullcalendar.min.js');
Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/custom/calendar.js');
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I've already download the required things, but Idk where to call the js. when I call it in my view, like how I call the calendar.js and fullcalendar.min.js :
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/js/plugins/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/js/custom/calendar.js"></script>

the calendar won't appears.

Comment: and where I have to put this code : **Yii::app()->ClientScript->registerCode('jquery.ui');** ?

Comment: thanks for your help @Sergey 
but unfortunately, I still can't get my event yet. can you tell me what is the correct URL to put into this _url: '/path/todirectory/index.php?r=task/getTasks',_ if my URL to getTasks in browser is: _http://localhost/~prg3/cpanelbee/calendar/getTasks_ ?

Comment: @dyooolicious, U write : `url: '/path/todirectory/protected/views/task/json-events.php',` and it's not correct, and I write down my solution. If you use `http://localhost/~prg3/cpanelbee/calendar/getTasks` it's good

Comment: thanks @Sergey I finally made it works. I just need to change this `echo json_encode($data);` into `echo CJSON::encode($data);` :D